# Problems solving - Asymptotic analysis

Tags: algorithm

I am new with running time. I couldn't solve this one.

**Given**

```
f(n) = log n^2 and g(n) = log n + 5
```

**prove**

```
f(n) = theta(g(n)).
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you mean theta(f(n)) = theta(g(n))?

Comment: no i mentioned one is the correct one.
log n^2 = theta( log n + 5)

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial. From basic logarithm properties

```
f(n) = log(n^2) = 2*log(n)
```

You need

```
C1*g(n) <= f(n) <= C2*g(n)
```

i.e.

```
C1*(log(n) + 5) <= 2*log(n)          (1)
```

and

```
2*log(n) <= C2*(log(n) + 5)          (2)
```

If you rewrite (1) as

```
C1*log(n) + C1*5 <= log(n) + log(n)
```

it looks like `C1 == 1` would be a good choice, so we get:

```
log(n) + 5 <= log(n) + log(n)
5 <= log(n)
n >= 32
```

So we get for `C1 == 1` and for each `n >= 32`, (1) holds.

For (2), it's obvious that you can choose `C2 == 2`. At the end you get

```
for each n >= 32
g(n) <= f(n) <= 2*g(n)
```

QED.